# Facebook Graph API Comment Doesn't Return From

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook comment and I would like to get the user ID of the author of the comment. I am able to get this information when the comment is posted **on the page that I own** with this query:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/**comment_id**?fields=from&access_token=**access_token**

However, the same does not work when I am accessing a comment that is not posted on my own page, the **from** field is never returned. Is it possible to get the author of a comment that is posted on a different page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the author of a comment that is posted on a different page?

No, that information is not available to you any more.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages:

> /page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data for objects owned by a Page.

Comment: Then why is still included in the documentation ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/comment#u_0_g

Comment: @Ionut why shouldn’t it be? The info is available, if you have page admin access. And the page you just referred to explicitly mentions this, _“Page-owned Comments and Replies — For any comments or replies on a Page, you must use a Page access token if you want User information to be included in the response.”_

Comment: I've used one of my pages access token, but `from` field still not returning anything. And then I thought, if it's not working, why there is still in the docs. The endpoint used `comment_id?fields=from&access_token=page_access_token`. Graph API `v2.12`. I've just tested it in the explorer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, used a wrong token, got the right one and it works now :D.

Comment: @lonut  how did you get the access token and what was the issue? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a development account you cannot get the from user details of a user who comments on your posts. You can however create test users from your developer account, login with the test account, comment and retrieve their from details.